# How to Include Another Library within a Library

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-library

I've made a Library that implements `androidx.annotation` but when I use that library in a app the app can't resolve `annotation`.

**build.gradle (Module : library)**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
}
```

**build.gradle (Module : app)**

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':library')
}
```

**MainActivity.java (app)**

```java
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // ...

   @NonNull
   public String getString() {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Whenever I try to Run App, it says no class found for `androidx.annotation.NonNull`. I want to Include `androidx.annotation` with my library. How can I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately the project in the link is no longer maintained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it is not working might be the way you have added the dependency. `Implementation` means that the dependency will only be available and accessible to the library module which explains why you're facing this.

Use `api` instead. It means that the dependency will also be available and accessible to the module that depends on this module.

Try this:

**build.gradle (Module : library)**

```
dependencies {
    api 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Now it works. I just changed all 'compile' to 'implementation', I didn't knew About 'api'. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't forget to mark as correct answer if it solved your problem. :)